# Golang: How to get LastInsertId from table with a create trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, go, auto-increment

Trying to get the AUTO_INCREMENT id from a table that has an INSERT/UPDATE trigger into a "changes" table. Initially my code was the standard pattern:

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT table SET name=?")
res, err := stmt.Exec(name)
lid, err := res.LastInsertId()
```

But the TRIGGER on the table was causing the LastInsertId to return the ID from the change table, and not the new record in the insert table.

Now I found that I could adjust my query to instead return the SCOPE_IDENTITY and that seemed to properly return the ID being inserted, the issue here was that if the INSERT failed, then the SCOPE_IDENTITY would return NULL and the Scan() would try to insert a NULL value into an INT64 variable. Which in and of itself is a simple handle of the value... the issue I have is what was the error on INSERT? I can't seem to get at the value of the error that caused the INSERT to fail so I can properly log the issue and pass the error back gracefully to be corrected.

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT table SET name=?; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY as last_insert_id")
res, err := stmt.QueryRow(name)

var lid int64
err := res.Scan(&lid)
```

I've tried using a transaction, but the moment the INSERT completes, the SCOPE closes and the next query in the transaction still returns NULL.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a workaround using a TRY CATCH TSQL statement.

```
    BEGIN TRY  
        INSERT table SET name=?; 
        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as last_insert_id;
    END TRY  
    BEGIN CATCH  
        THROW;
    END CATCH;
```

Then using the QueryRow, if there is an error within the INSERT, the CATCH will throw the error for handling.